# Irreducible representation of derivatives of diabatic electronic wave functions

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, symmetry, group-theory, quantum-chemistry

My question regards the symmetry properties of the derivatives of *diabatic electronic wavefunctions*. I think the question goes somewhat beyond the standard group theoretical machinery taught in introductory quantum mechanics classes, so I will try to give some context without reviewing all the details. Consider first the electronic Hamiltonian for a molecular system:
\begin{equation} \tag{1}
    H_\mathrm{e} = T_\mathrm{e} + U(\mathbf{r},\mathbf{Q})
\end{equation}
Here, $T_\mathrm{e}$ denotes the kinetic energy of the electrons while $U(\mathbf{r},\mathbf{Q})$ denotes the potential energy of the molecular system (i.e. the electron-electron repulsion, electron-nuclear attraction and nuclear-nuclear repulsion). The potential energy term depends on the electronic coordinates $\mathbf{r}$ as well as the nuclear coordinates $\mathbf{Q}$.
The eigenfunctions of $H_\mathrm{e}$ are given by
\begin{equation} \tag{2}
    H_\mathrm{e} \Phi_i(\mathbf{r}, \mathbf{Q}) 
    = V_i(\mathbf{Q}) \Phi_i(\mathbf{r}, \mathbf{Q})
\end{equation}
I will denote the eigenfunctions $\Phi_i(\mathbf{r}, \mathbf{Q})$ by the term *adiabatic electronic wavefunctions*. They depend parametrically on the nuclear coordinates and transform according to some irreducible representation of the pertinent molecular point group. In the context of non-adiabatic molecular dynamics, it is sometimes advantageous to use a different electronic basis, namely a so-called *diabatic electronic basis*. This basis is generally obtained by transforming the adiabatic basis according to a $\mathbf{Q}$-dependent unitary matrix $\mathbf{S}(\mathbf{Q})$, which is optimal in some suitable sense [1]. Thus, the diabatic wavefunctions are written as
\begin{equation} \tag{3}
    \tilde{\Phi}_i(\mathbf{r}, \mathbf{Q}) = \sum_j S_{ij}(\mathbf{Q}) \Phi_j(\mathbf{r}, \mathbf{Q})
\end{equation}
where the coefficients $S_{ij}(\mathbf{Q})$ are elements of $\mathbf{S}(\mathbf{Q})$. It turns out [1] that we may enforce the condition
\begin{equation} \tag{4}
    \tilde{\Phi}_i(\mathbf{r}, \mathbf{Q} = 0) 
    = \Phi_i(\mathbf{r}, \mathbf{Q} = 0)
\end{equation}
without loss of generality. Since $\Phi_i(\mathbf{r}, \mathbf{Q})$ transforms according to some irreducible representation (say, $\Gamma_{\!i}$) we also know that $\tilde{\Phi}_i(\mathbf{r}, \mathbf{Q} = 0)$ transforms according to $\Gamma_{\!i}$. Away from $\mathbf{Q} = 0$, the symmetry properties of $\tilde{\Phi}_i(\mathbf{r}, \mathbf{Q})$ are unknown.

We furthermore assume that the nuclear coordinates $\mathbf{Q} = (Q_1, Q_2, \ldots, Q_f)$ have been chosen so they each transform according to some irreducible representation of the point group. What I need to know is how the derivatives of the diabatic wavefunctions with respect to the nuclear coordinates transform under the symmetry operations of the point group. Specifically, I am interested in finding the irreducible representation of derivatives such as
\begin{equation} \tag{5}
    \biggl. 
    \frac{\partial \tilde{\Phi}_i}{\partial Q_s}
    \bigg\rvert_{\mathbf{Q} = 0}
\end{equation}
in the abstract case where the transformation $\mathbf{S}(\mathbf{Q})$ is not known. This means that we know nothing about the $\tilde{\Phi}_i(\mathbf{Q})$ except that Eq. (4) holds.
I already know [2, p. 129] that the operator $\partial/\partial Q_s$ transforms as the coordinate $Q_s$. I am tempted to say that the irreducible representation of Eq. (5) is given by
\begin{equation} \tag{6}
    \Gamma_{\!(5)} = \Gamma_{\!\partial/\partial Q_s} \otimes \Gamma_{\!i} = \Gamma_{\!Q_s} \otimes \Gamma_{\!i}
\end{equation}
but I have not been able to prove this (I have tried substituting Eq. (3) into Eq. (5) but this did work out).

I am asking in the context of a computational model known as the vibronic coupling Hamiltonian [3] (VCHAM). The literature on the VCHAM makes heavy use of certain symmetry-based selection rules to determine vanishing parameters and thus simplify the model. I have not been able to find any proofs of these rules but they would follow almost trivially if Eq. (6) holds. Indeed, my unqualified feeling is that Eq. (6) must hold in order for the selection rules to be true.

This is my first question on Stack Exchange so I hope it makes sense.

References:

[1] G. A. Worth and L. S. Cederbaum. *Beyond Born-Oppenheimer: Molecular dynamics through a conical intersection*. Annu. Rev. Phys. Chem. 55, 1 (2004). http://dx.doi.org/10.1146/annurev.physchem.55.091602.094335.

[2] A. J. Ceulemans. *Group Theory Applied to Chemistry*. Springer (2013). ISBN 978-94-007-6863-5. http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-94-007-6863-5.

[3] G. A. Worth, H.-D. Meyer and L. S. Cederbaum. *Multidimensional dynamics involving a conical intersection: Wavepacket calculations using the MCTDH method*. In W. Domcke, D. R. Yarkony and H. Köppel (editors). *Conical Intersections: Electronic Structure, Dynamics & Spectroscopy*, Chapter 14. World Scientific (2004). https://www.pci.uni-heidelberg.de/tc/usr/mctdh/lit/ci-book.pdf.